# Using ActivityTestRule for multiple activities in an Espresso Test

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a test that I want to get working in espresso to fetch all (100+) Activities in my app and assert that they start an Intent to launch a dialog activity. The test works perfecting on the first activity in the list (or if there is just one activity), but fails on the second activity, because espresso tries to cast it to the first activity.

I have to use ActivityTestRule and not launch the activity directly from the context, or Intendo intended assertions don't work.

Most of the documentation shows espresso being setup with one activity per test, which is not possible in my case, because I'm loading the list of activities dynamically.

Espresso is saving some kind of internal state that I can't figure out how to clear. Does anyone know how to clear it between assertions in a for loop?

Or is there another class other than ActivityTestRule without the internal state that also works with intended?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to test:

```
ActivityInfo[] activities =
    appContext
        .getPackageManager()
        .getPackageInfo(appContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        .activities;

for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : activities) {
  String className = activityInfo.name;
  ActivityTestRule activityTestRule =
      new ActivityTestRule<>((Class<Activity>) Class.forName(className));
  Intent intent = new Intent()
      .setClassName(appContext, className)
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  activityActivityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);

  intended(hasComponent(ExpectedDialogActivity.class.getName()));

  activityActivityTestRule.finishActivity();
}
```